# Generating Faker data with node.js

Tags: node.js, faker

I am trying to generate faker data to a localhost, but everytime i run the command "**node fakerdata.js**", the terminal returns nothing, it just returns "**Jacks-MacBook-Air-3:newlayout jackdeazley$** ", any ideas as to why this is?

Below is my file fakerdata.js:

```js
var faker = require("faker");

module.exports = function() {
    var students = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        students.push({
            id: i,
            firstname: faker.name.firstName(),
            secondaryname: faker.name.lastName(),
            phone: faker.phone.phoneNumber(),
            address: faker.address.streetAddress(),
            email: faker.internet.email(),
            
        })
    }
    
    return {
        "students":students
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lack of understanding of how javascript modules works in your part. You can check out [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascript-modules-a-beginner-s-guide-783f7d7a5fcc?gi=2f3495f54207) link or other resources regarding how these JS modules work.

the `fakerdata.js` is a module. And you need to `require` or `import` this file from another js file.

**newfile.js**

```
const fdata = require('./fakerdata');
console.log(fdata());
```

Then do:

**`$ node newfile.js`**

In order to use it with express here is one very minimal example to give you a headstart:

newfile.js

```
const express = require('express');
const fakeData = require('./fakerdata');
const app = express();
const port = 8080
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    return res.json(fakeData());
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on PORT ${port}`);
});
```

**`$ node newfile.js`**
Then go to `http://localhost:8080/` it should show the output.

Comment: Great thanks, is there a way I could display the faker data on the browser using express rather than viewing it on the terminal?

Comment: Edited the answer for the express part. Please note this is a very very minimal example

Comment: Perfect, thanks Aritra! Port 8080 wasnt working for me so I tried 3001 and it was spot on, thanks again!